# What is the [capture] in lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11

Using the lambda to expand an AES key, it has shown this error:

```
no suitable conversion function from "lambda []int (std::__1::string prekey)->int" to "int" exists
```

The code I am using is:

```cpp
int expandedkey = [] (std::string prekey, int bit) -> int {};
```

This is what I found on Wikipedia describing lambdas, and I do not know that is the [capture] in it.

```cpp
[capture] (args) -> return_type {body}
```

Standard:GNU++ 11

Comment: Note that the error you see is completely unrelated to the capture lists. Lambda is not an `int` type. Since typename for lambda is generated by the compiler, you need to use `auto` to deduce type of variable in which lambda will be saved.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks. It solves my problem.